# Using chrome.tabs.executeScript to populate multiple-select fields

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have looked on here for similar queries, but I'm struggling to find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm writing a very basic chrome extension, which will allow users to populate frequently used forms (basically there's one form that's huge, which users have to complete, but a lot of the information never changes).

The form itself isn't mine, so I can't edit it at all and it's set up like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="SelectField">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</Option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</Option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</Option>
</select>
```

I'm using the following to inject values into text fields, and that's not causing any problems:

```
document.getElementById("TextField").value = "Text Field Value";
```

The issue I'm having is there are a bunch of multiple select boxes on the form, and in cases where I only need to pre-fill one value, the above works fine. however, if I need to select multiple options it won't work.

I've tried various naive attempts such as:

```
document.getElementById("SelectField").value = "Option 1","Option 3";
document.getElementById("SelectField").values = "Option 1","Option 3";
document.getElementById("SelectField").value = ["Option 1","Option 3"];
document.getElementById("SelectField").values = ["Option 1","Option 3"];
```

But of course none of these are working. in some cases it selects the first option, in other cases nothing at all.

I'd also rather not use jQuery if at all possible.

Comment: What does JSON have to do with the question?

Comment: You're right, at the moment, nothing. Eventually I will be pulling the field info from a JSON file, but you're right, this question isn't JSON-specific - I've edited it to be clearer

Comment: Is this specific to one site? (In this case, a better strategy is to always inject a content script, and use Messaging instead of script injection to interact with it)

Comment: You could do both: use `tabs.executeScript()` and send a message with the data. Which is more appropriate depends on how often the automatic-filling will be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of multiple options select you need first to add (if they are not a multiple selects)

```
document.getElementById("SelectField").multiple = true;
```

then you can do

```
document.getElementById("SelectField").options[0].selected=true;
document.getElementById("SelectField").options[1].selected=true;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#SelectField option[value="Option1"]').selected = true
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but unfortunately that's not worked for me. I've edited my question above to give a little more detail?

Comment: I have edited the response for you accessing by the index

Comment: This will work - is it possible to pick the option using the option value rather than it's index? Just incase they add options to the select, which would mess with all the numbers?

Comment: That's great thank you - just one last question... I'm using this to inject the code into a chrome tab, so at the moment it's like this:

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
code: 'document.querySelector("#SelectField option[value="Option 1"]").selected=true;' });

But that's not working - I'm sure it's the quotes within quotes? Sorry for the barrage of questions

Comment: yes it is use it so either you use the escape the quotes inside the js query  by using \"

Comment: @Ryad.iv, Actually, at the moment, he can not [up-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).  Once he has 15 reputation he will be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For [`<select multiple="true">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) elements you have the set the `selected` property on each individual `<option>` element.

You could so something like this:

```js
var optionsToSelect = ["Option 1","Option 3"];

optionsToSelect.forEach(option => {
    document.querySelector('#SelectField option[value="'+option+'"]').selected = true;
});
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" id="SelectField">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</Option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</Option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</Option>
</select>
```

You are pulling this information out of JSON from some record.  That implies that you might be doing selections on multiple elements, and that there is the possibility that the JSON data may include options that don't exists at this time or IDs for `<select>` elements that don't exist.  Thus, something that is a bit more generic, efficient and robust should be used. Obviously, it becomes a bit more complex:

```js
var optionsToSelect = ["Option 1","Option 3"];

setMultipleOptionsById('SelectField',optionsToSelect);

function setMultipleOptionsById(id,selectedOptions) {
    let selectEl = document.getElementById(id);
    if(selectEl){
        selectedOptions.forEach(option => {
            let optionEl = selectEl.querySelector('option[value="'+option+'"]');
            if(optionEl) {
                optionEl.selected = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" id="SelectField">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</Option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</Option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</Option>
</select>
```

Currently, the above function just quietly ignores any missing `<select>` or `<option>` elements.  If you desired, it would be easy to add a return value to the function which indicated if there was a missing element, and could report what element was missing.

Comment: Thank you, I'm struggling to implement it, but that may be because of the way I need to do it.

As it's code in a popup of an extension, I need to inject it into the page, and I'm struggling to work it.

As things stand I have something like this:

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
    code:    'document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "Value 1"' +
                 'document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = "Value 2"' +
                 etc...});'`

I'm not too worried about making it super efficient, and happy to write each line, but not sure how to. Does this make sense?

Comment: You should probably make a more generic content script and just send it the array of options.

Comment: I agree with Xan. Having a content script you inject and then it accepts a message, with an array of objects describing the ID and values to fill, sounds like a better idea than to hard code everything. Alternately, it could pull the information from `chrome.storage` if you are already storing it.